# How to install xcode 8 from terminal in vagrant?

Tags: xcode, macos, vagrant

Having a running vagrant instance of macosx 10-12, when running 
    `xcode-select --install`
I get:
    `xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools.` 
But the problem is nothing pops up and it finishes on that. What should I do in this case? I also cannot download the xcode 8 package manually from the store as only install option is present and there is no gui in vagrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to download .xip file of xcode and install it. Below is the link to download xcode or anyother development tool for apple developer.

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Yes apple also requires to download them on mac computer, otherwise there will be an error on download.